# Convert multiple columns to one column

Tags: python, r, list

I'm looking to merge multiple columns to one column.

Here's my current dataset :

```
Column A  Column B   Column C 
    a1       b1        c1 
    b2       a2        e2
```

I am looking for the following as output

```
Column D  
  a1
  b1
  c1
  b2 
  a2
  e2
```

Is this possible ? Using R or Python ?

Comment: easy in python but is that _really_ your format? with all the spaces and no quotes? how are we supposed to parse that using a standard csv module?

Comment: Similarly, easy in `R`, but the same questions apply about how your data is actually structured.

Comment: Well, this is just a mock how the data set would look. The live data in an excel for now having clear demarcations and I can add in quotes if that's the way to go about it. Keen to see the solution in R or python.

Comment: Something as easy as: `data.frame(ColumnD=unlist(df,use.names=F))`? Or even: `data.frame(ColumnD=c(t(df)))` would probably be better.

Comment: @MikeyMike - Thank you. The output in the second one was what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the data that you provided, in the format you provided, you could do this with:

```
data.frame(ColumnD=c(t(df)))

  ColumnD
1      a1
2      b1
3      c1
4      b2
5      a2
6      e2
```

We transpose the data, then combine it.